# my server could not find my handlebars templates after deployment to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have my express app running on localhost without any error, but when I deploy it to heroku am getting an error:

> GET / 500 24.258 ms - 148
> 2021-02-12T03:19:34.225902+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to lookup view "form" in views directory "/views".

[image: Screenshot of VS Code files]

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly your folder structure.

```
node-app
  ├──views
  │  └──err.handlebars
  │  └──form.handlebars
  │  └──thanks.handlebars
  ├──main.js
  └──package.json
```

When you deploy on Heroku it puts the content of `node-app` in the directory `/app`.

You are executing `node main.js`. `main.js` resides in the folder `/app` thus your `__dirname` is `/app`.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "../views"));
```

This sets your `views` directory to:

```
__dirname + "../views" = "/app" + "../views" = "/views"
```

Thus you are getting the error message:

```
Failed to lookup view "form" in views directory "/views".
```

It should be:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "./views"));
```

which would become: `/app/views`. This is where your handlebars are actually located.

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested but it doesn't work also